# Azure Storage Blob without Autofac

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, autofac, asp.net-core-webapi

We are developing .NET Core 3.0 Web-API to upload images to Azure blob storage. I came across a sample to achieve the same.

Below is the portion from Startup.cs which makes use of Autofac, specifically ContainerBuilder and IComponentContext.

```
        private static void ConfigureStorageAccount(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            AzureTableStorageDebugConnectionString = Configuration["Azure:Storage:ConnectionString"];

            builder.Register(c => CreateStorageAccount(AzureTableStorageDebugConnectionString));
        }

        private static CloudStorageAccount CreateStorageAccount(string connection)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connection))
            {
                throw new Exception("Azure Storage connection string is null!");
            }
            return CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection);
        }

        private static void ConfigureServicesWithRepositories(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ImageUploadService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();           
        }

        private static void ConfigureAzureCloudBlobContainers(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<CloudStorageAccount>().CreateCloudBlobClient());

            builder.Register(c => GetBlobContainer(c, UploadedImagesCloudBlobContainerName))
                .Named<CloudBlobContainer>(UploadedImagesCloudBlobContainerName);
        }

        private static CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(IComponentContext context, string blobContainerName)
        {
            var blob = context.Resolve<CloudBlobClient>().GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);

            var createdSuccessfully = blob.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Result;

            if (createdSuccessfully)
            {
                blob.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });
            }

            return blob;
        }

        private static void ConfigureCloudBlobContainersForServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ImageUploadService>()
                   .WithParameter(
                       (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == (typeof(CloudBlobContainer)),
                       (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<CloudBlobContainer>(UploadedImagesCloudBlobContainerName))
                       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
```

Is it possible to get rid of Autofac completely and use Core 3.0 to achieve the same functionality in Startup.cs?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is your goal? I don't think the implementation you provided is good...

Comment: `Startup` should not upload files to the blob. Your service should do it, based on the request

Comment: @MartinBrandl The goal is to upload image to Azure Blob storage without using Autofac.

Comment: @HariHaran In the above Startup.cs code, there is no upload. The upload implementation is in service.

Comment: @HariHaran Yes, it is copied from a blog but it is not meaningless. I also want to implement repository pattern in .NET Core 3.0 Web-API. Autofac acts as Inversion of Control container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Autofac is used for DI. If you do not want to use it, you can directly upload contents to your storage account as following:

```
string connString = "the connection string from portal for your storage account, DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagetest789;AccountKey=G36m***==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer =cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("container_name");
cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob_name");
cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile("file_path");
```

### Suggestion:

To avoid re-creating `CloudBlobClient`, you can create a factory class, which can produce `CloudBlobContainer` or `CloudBlockBlob` directly.

And, you can use [Microsoft official DI implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0). And register your factory in `Starup`.

```
//For example, the interface is IStorageFactory, and your implementation is MyStroageFactory
services.AddSingleton<IStorageFactory, MyStroageFactory>();
```

And then, you can inject the factory. For example, in a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private IStorageFactory _myStorageFactory;

    public HomeController(IStorageFactory myStorageFactory)
    {
        _myStorageFactory = myStorageFactory;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //For example, I defined a getCloudBlockBlob method in factory
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = _myStorageFactory.getCloudBlockBlob("container_name","blob_name");
        cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(....);

        return Ok("Uploaded!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack Jia. I have initiated cloudBlobContainer in the constructor of the factory class.